# How do I download flutter native splash

Tags: flutter

So I have just added flutter_native_splash to dev_dependencies and I am doing it by a tutorial on YT but don't know how the guy in the video has downloaded this so there is more about native splash...

[image: code]

Comment: What IDE/Editor do you using?

Comment: VS code, but I already fixed it so it's cool now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change it to this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.0
```

then press `Ctrl + S` or just save the file and now Press this button if you use Vscode (other editors propably have something similar):
[image]

Comment: oh so I did it right but just didn't realised...ok thanks anyways

Comment: happens to all of us, np :)